# array not saving input

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, tkinter

hey back again with the same code, well edited so it works better. anyway trying to add the button input into the array and that works. what doesn't work is the fact every time i call the function do() the values reset due to them being local. i tried to fix this by making it global(within the class) using the self.store array. this didn't seem to fix the problem so if someone could help would be much appreciated here is the relevant code

```
def __init__(self,master):#is the master for the button widgets
        self.count=0
        self.store=["0"]
        frame=Frame(master)
        frame.pack()
        self.addition = Button(frame, text="+", command=self.add)#when clicked sends a call back for a +
        self.addition.pack()
        self.subtraction = Button(frame, text="-", command=self.sub)#when clicked sends a call back for a -
        self.subtraction.pack()
        self.equate = Button(frame, text="=", command=self.equate)#when clicked sends a call back for a =
        self.equate.pack()
        self.one = Button(frame, text="1", command=self.one)#when clicked sends a call back for a -
        self.one.pack()

def add(self):
    self.do("+")
    self.count=self.count+1

def sub(self):
    self.do("-")
    self.count=self.count+1

def equate(self):
    self.do("=")

def one(self):
    self.do("1")
    self.count=self.count+1

def do(self, X):#will hopefully colaborate all of the inputs
    cont, num = True, 0
    strstore="3 + 8"#temporarily used to make sure the calculating works
    self.store=["2","1","+","2","3","4"]#holds the numbers used to calculate.
    for num in range(1):
        if X == "=":
            cont = False
        self.store[self.count]=X
        print(self.store[self.count])
        print(self.store[:])#test code
    if cont == False:
        print(self.eval_binary_expr(*(strstore.split())))
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do at all... But some comments. First `range(1)` is equal to `[0]` which I don't think you want. What are you expecting your code to do?

Comment: its going to end up being a calculator what im trying to do is turn a button press on the screen into an array that i can calculate from but even then ive used a split later down(not in the extract) so i need to use a string rather than array. anyway button press saves into an array(self.store) but as its in a function its a local variable as such every time i press a new button the location i am in the array changes however it does not keep my last button saved because it is local. i want to know how to make self.store keep its value.

Comment: `self.store` **does** keep it's value. You just overwrite it every time in `do`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
self.store=["2","1","+","2","3","4"]
```

If you initialize it this way in the do function, self.store will be reset to ["2","1","+","2","3","4"] every time you call do(X)
Initialize it outside of the do function if you don't want it to be overwritten.

But if you want to add a value to a list, use append(), extend, or += operator:

```
self.store+=["2","1","+","2","3","4"]
```

(if you want it to be done only once, do it in the constructor, __init__ function!)

also,

```
self.store[self.count]=X
```

If you try to append to the END of the list self.store, you should just do:

```
self.store.append(X)
```

This way, you won't need to count anything, with the risk of forgetting an incrementation and replacing a value by X instead of appending X.

As said above, range(1), it's 0...

Let's do it another way:

```
def do(self, X):
    cont, num = True, 0
    liststore=['3', '+', '8']#splitting your string.
    #initialize str.store elsewhere!

    if X == "=":    
        cont = False
    self.store.append("X")
    print(self.store[-1])#getting the last
    print(self.store)#the same as self.store[:]
    if cont == False:
        print(self.eval_binary_expr(*(liststore)))
```

Simpler, and probably better.
Last thing: in Python, you are usually working with lists (like self.store), not arrays (which come from the module array)